# How to change IIS Pool Process Integrity Level

Tags: windows, user-accounts, uac, iis, windows-server-2019

I can not locate **where can I change the Integrity Level of an account** that's run a Pool on IIS

On this capture you can see that One pool is run with High Integrity and the other with Medium. The high means that run like the "run as administrator" on a program. But how to change that for an IIS Pool ?

[image: Process Explorer Integrity Level]

I have look - and compare the accounts on this computer and among other servers - but I was unable to locate anything relative.

- On IIS | Application Pools | Pool Name | Advanced Settings
- Running the Local Security Police | Local Policies | all the settings there
- Computer Management | Local Users and Groups | on the user accounts.
- Settings | Accounts | Other users , nothing here

Comment: Are all of your application pools using the same .NET CLR version?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes they are - and on an other server all they are high - but can not find why...

Comment: The only other difference is your user. The High integrity app pool is running with the default app pool identity, but the others are running under another identity. What settings do you need to change on the identity to increase the integrity, I don't know, but maybe try changing one to use the default identity to see if the integrity changes. This then gives you something else to go and look at.

Comment: @spikey_richie On an other server they are run under High Integrity, so its not the default pool, its the user that set this up, or the process that starts the pool and set this - but where I can control that Integrity ?

Comment: I don't know. If you don't get any traction in here, you might consider asking the question in https://serverfault.com/ too.